# rasterizing for maxent?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, maxent

Im working with MAXENT and im having trouble using some shapefile files with critical variables. I rasterized the shapefiles into rasters selecting one attribute from the attribute table, but before rasterizing, the software asks me to select CELL SIZE. I understand this is the resolution. The world clim .bil that I want to compare to this shapefile has a resolution of: 0,00833 The default CELL SIZE when I try to rasterize the shapefile is 0.15 
So: 
1) How do I know the shapefile resolution or CELL SIZE? 
2) If I change the 0.15 to 0,008333, the raster is generated anyway. How do I know the data I'm obtaining is usable for analysis anyway?

And the other question:
When I rasterize the shapefile, I get a folder with various .adf files

How to I convert these files into a format that the MAXENT can read, such as .grd or .bil ?

Comment: What's the link between maxent and Arcgis (seen in your tags) ?

Comment: Use the documented resolution. ArcGIS makes a guess based on the extent

Comment: As per the [Tour] please ask just one question per question, and explain how ArcGIS Desktop is used related to the one that you decide to ask.

Comment: For Maxent, you have to align rasters to exactly same extent and cell size. Not ArcGIS user, but I think there is some  raster "snap" (or align) function. So rasterize your vector to cell size depend on how much are features detalied. If they are detalied it will be better set 0.008333 (or less). Than if this raster differ (extent,cell size) from Wordclim, align it.